# How to send apache logs from one container to a logstash in another container?

Tags: docker, logging, containers, elastic-stack

For the last three days I've been trying to gather all logs from the containers I have in my Docker and send them to Logstash. I've been working with the ELK Stack (Elasticsearch, Logstash and Kibana) and I'm using Logspout as the router for this logs.

All three instances of the ELK Stack are running in a different containers. I've followed [this setup](https://nathanleclaire.com/blog/2015/04/27/automating-docker-logging-elasticsearch-logstash-kibana-and-logspout/).

My current Logstash configuration file looks like this:

```
input {
  tcp {
    port => 5000
    type => syslog
  }
  udp {
    port => 5000
    type => syslog
  }
}

filter {
  if [type] == "syslog" {
    grok {
      match => { "message" => "%{SYSLOG5424PRI}%{NONNEGINT:ver} +(?:%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:ts}|-) +(?:%{HOSTNAME:containerid}|-) +(?:%{NOTSPACE:containername}|-) +(?:%{NOTSPACE:proc}|-) +(?:%{WORD:msgid}|-) +(?:%{SYSLOG5424SD:sd}|-|) +%{GREEDYDATA:msg}" }
    }
    syslog_pri { }
    date {
      match => [ "syslog_timestamp", "MMM  d HH:mm:ss", "MMM dd HH:mm:ss" ]
    }
    if !("_grokparsefailure" in [tags]) {
      mutate {
        replace => [ "@source_host", "%{syslog_hostname}" ]
        replace => [ "@message", "%{syslog_message}" ]
      }
    }
    mutate {
      remove_field => [ "syslog_hostname", "syslog_message", "syslog_timestamp" ]
    }
  }
}

output {
  elasticsearch { host => "elasticsearch" }
  stdout { codec => rubydebug }
}
```

My current problem is that I'm logging pretty much every event necessary except for the errors and access logs from my apache2 container called laravel2. It logs some events from the container but not everything. If I produce an error by changing the index.php file it won't log properly in elasticsearch.

**What type of configuration should I have to be able to get this apache logs (both access and errors)?** I've seen some solutions around but they have as input a file which I'm not able to do since I'm running things in different containers.

EDIT:

My new logstash.sample.conf file:

```
input {
  tcp {
    port => 5000
    type => syslog
  }
  udp {
    port => 5000
    type => syslog
  }
  beats {
    # The port to listen on for filebeat connections.
    port => 5044
    # The IP address to listen for filebeat connections.
    host => "0.0.0.0"
    type => apachelog
  }
}

filter {
  if [type] == "apachelog" {
    grok {
      match => { "message" => ["%{IPORHOST:[apache2][access][remote_ip]} - %{DATA:[apache2][access][user_name]} \[%{HTTPDATE:[apache2][access][time]}\] \"%{WORD:[apache2][access][method]} %{DATA:[apache2][access][url]} HTTP/%{NUMBER:[apache2][access][http_version]}\" %{NUMBER:[apache2][access][response_code]} %{NUMBER:[apache2][access][body_sent][bytes]}( \"%{DATA:[apache2][access][referrer]}\")?( \"%{DATA:[apache2][access][agent]}\")?",
        "%{IPORHOST:[apache2][access][remote_ip]} - %{DATA:[apache2][access][user_name]} \\[%{HTTPDATE:[apache2][access][time]}\\] \"-\" %{NUMBER:[apache2][access][response_code]} -" ] }
      remove_field => "message"
    }
    mutate {
      add_field => { "read_timestamp" => "%{@timestamp}" }
    }
    date {
      match => [ "[apache2][access][time]", "dd/MMM/YYYY:H:m:s Z" ]
      remove_field => "[apache2][access][time]"
    }
    useragent {
      source => "[apache2][access][agent]"
      target => "[apache2][access][user_agent]"
      remove_field => "[apache2][access][agent]"
    }
    geoip {
      source => "[apache2][access][remote_ip]"
      target => "[apache2][access][geoip]"
    }
  }
  if [type] == "syslog" {
    grok {
      match => { "message" => "%{SYSLOG5424PRI}%{NONNEGINT:ver} +(?:%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:ts}|-) +(?:%{HOSTNAME:containerid}|-) +(?:%{NOTSPACE:containername}|-) +(?:%{NOTSPACE:proc}|-) +(?:%{WORD:msgid}|-) +(?:%{SYSLOG5424SD:sd}|-|) +%{GREEDYDATA:msg}" }
    }
    syslog_pri { }
    date {
      match => [ "syslog_timestamp", "MMM  d HH:mm:ss", "MMM dd HH:mm:ss" ]
    }
    if !("_grokparsefailure" in [tags]) {
      mutate {
        replace => [ "@source_host", "%{syslog_hostname}" ]
        replace => [ "@message", "%{syslog_message}" ]
      }
    }
    mutate {
      remove_field => [ "syslog_hostname", "syslog_message", "syslog_timestamp" ]
    }
  }
}

output {
  elasticsearch { 
    host => "elasticsearch"
  }
  stdout { codec => rubydebug }
}
```

And my filebeat.full.yml file:

```
#----------------------------- Logstash output ---------------------------------
#output.logstash:
  # Boolean flag to enable or disable the output module.
  enabled: true

  # The Logstash hosts
  hosts: ["localhost:5044"]
```

And to round off this, my filebeat.yml file:

```
filebeat.prospectors:
- input_type: log
  paths:
    - /var/log/apache2/access.log*
    - /var/log/apache2/other_vhosts_access.log*
  exclude_files: [".gz$"]

output.logstash:
  hosts: ["localhost:5044"]

processors:
- add_cloud_metadata:

output.elasticsearch:
  hosts: ['elasticsearch:9200']
  username: elastic
  password: changeme
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably, your apache2 container is logging access and errors to stdout only.

One option you have is to add another container that runs `filebeat` configured to push data to logstash (you'll need to adjust logstash config, too), make a shared volume between your apache container and this new container, finally, make apache write logs in the sared volume.

Take a look at [this](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/running-on-docker.html) link for how to run filebeat on docker

Take a look at [this](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/config-filebeat-logstash.html) link for how to configure filebeat to send data to logstash

Finally, look [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/logstash-config-for-filebeat-modules.html) to enable logstash to receive data from filebeat

First of all, you need to create a shared volume:

```
docker volume create --name apache-logs
```

After that, your can run your docker containers like this:

```
docker run -v apache-logs:/var/log/apache2 ... apache:version
docker run -v apache-logs:/var/log/apache2 ... filebeat:version
```

This way the 2 container will have a shared directory. You'll need to adjust apache in order to write its logs into /var/log/apache2 and setup filebeat in order to forward data from /var/log/apache2 to logstash.

Comment: Do I have to create a new docker image for apache in order to share the volume?

Comment: Not for sharing the volume, but depending on how you want to do that you may need to create one custom image to adjust Apache's config files

Comment: I'm still a bit green in Docker, I'm not sure how to do it, but I'll try, thank you.

Comment: I'll try to help you a little in the answer

Comment: Thanks a lot for your effort, still didn't manage to put it to work but I'll keep trying.

Comment: Where are you stuck exactly?

Comment: Completed your steps (mentioned in the answer) and now filebeat won't keep running after i start its container. It just exits right away. I assume it's some kind of error in the files I had to edit (filebeat.yml and filebeat.full.yml)

Comment: Post em and the output

Comment: Edited the question with more details

Comment: In filebeat.full.yml uncomment `output.logstash`. plus, your host is wrong. Logstash is not at localhost from the filebeat container's perspective . Finally, you only need one output config for filebeat: either logstash or elasticsearch, but not both!

Comment: I think I managed to finally get it to work thanks to you. A huge thank you @whites11

Comment: My pleasure. Glad to help